# Violation of UNIQUE KEY Contstraints - Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I am pulling out my hair over here.  I have a table that has a UNIQUE Key (IX_tblTable) and the unique key is on a column Number.  I am parsing some data from the web and storing it in the table.  My latest collection of data from the web contains number **THAT ARE NOT CONTAINED IN THE DATABASE**.  so I am getting data from the site and all of the data I am getting in unique, there are no duplicates and the numbers in the list that is returned are not in the database.

I keep getting this error everytime I try to update the database, what is the best way to trap the error to see which number is throwing the error.  I am storing everything that comes back in an object list and when it is done running I have 131 records that need to be inserted and I can not see which one is throwing this error.  What is the bast way to trap it?

EDIT: I am using sql server 2005, wirtting in C# and using Linq2SQL.  I can not post any c# code at this time for proprietary reasons...

Comment: You should indicate what SQL engine you are using, and any other details that may seem relevant.

Comment: Post some code and DB access technology (JDBC, ADO.NET, PHP) to see if you can get some more help.

Comment: Check for triggers. They might add data as well (like history...)

Comment: Assuming you are using something like c# or VB to pump that data in, why don't you just do a quick and nasty Debug.WriteLine(data) for each row you insert, the last one written to the output window before the error occurs will be the one causing the problem.

Comment: @slugster - I have tried that, the only issue is that I am checking each record as it goes through to make sure its unique and adding all the unique ones to a list and then adding the entire collection to the database at one time....

Comment: Is your UNIQUE Key auto generated?

Comment: @norlando02 - No the UNIQUE key is on the number field which is data that is being pulled from the web.

Comment: Seems to me Slugster still has the right answer: Just temporarily modify your insert to do one record at a time, and print out each record before you add it. Once you see the bad one, maybe you'll have a clue to root causes.

Comment: When you say you verify that each incoming key value is unique, do you compare each one to what's already on the database, or do you compare the new ones to each other? If you don't do both, that could be where the duplication lies.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just disable your constraint for a while and see what duplicates save? Later you can remove duplicates and re-enable it.

Comment: I never thought about trying that, good idea I will post with results soon

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the table without a primary key or uniqueness constraint (having the column, just not as a primary). Modify your code to insert into that table. Run it. Select values having more than one duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm called [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the 'wrong' data.

Suppose you have 131 lines of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)` and you want to catch the one that's causing the error, you can divide your 131 lines into two pices(first 66 and last 65). Now run that 66 and 65 INSERTs separatelly, and see which throws the error. Continue to 'divide an try' until you get to one single line. (That's 10 tries in the worst case).

Answer (score 0):

Are you controlling the lifecycle of your datacontext?

```
Insert 5
SubmitChanges (record inserted, no exception)
Insert 5
SubmitChanges (duplicateKeyException on 5)
Insert 6
SubmitChanges (duplicateKeyException on 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Begin Try... End Try.. Begin Catch... End Catch... in the SQL store procedure (I assume you use the SP to insert data) to capture the Row that causes the unique constraint violation?